# Using safe core sdk and creating the instance of EthAdapter

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I am trying to create the instance of safe core sdk but it shows me an error such as ** TypeError: Web3Adapter is not a constructor**.

````
const Web3Adapter = require('@safe-global/safe-web3-lib');
const SafeServiceClient = require('@safe-global/safe-service-client');

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const safeOwner = '0x378367eb35a793817aD92ae055394E4A6CF1A0FF';

const ethAdapter = new Web3Adapter({
  web3,
  signerAddress: safeOwner
})```
````